# Xamarion IOS LexDB Save - exception attempting to JIT compile (wrapper delegate-invoke)

Tags: ios, database, xamarin

I'm using LexDb.iOS 1.2 in a xamarin ios application.

If i Execute in the emulator evrithings goes perfectly, but if I debug in a ios phone then:

When I try to do the

db.Save(item);

throws this exception:

Attemptin to JIT compile method '(wrapper delegate-invoke):invoke_callvirt_Nullable'1_User(Entities)' while running with --aot only. See http://xamarinsupport for more information.)

I have to do somthing different when I execute in the phone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all a problem with the Profile of the PCL that I used in the xamarin.

I changed all the PCL to use Profile78 and then all worked so far.