# Xamarin, updating app to Unified mvvmCross not compiling

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

After update existing app to the Unified API, and update the mvvmCross libraries to 3.5, when I try to compile in Iphone the nex error is show:

Failed to resolve "System.Boolean Cirrious.VvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject::ShowViewModel(Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxBundle,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxRequestedBy)" reference from "Cirrious.MvvmCross, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublickKeyToken = e16445fd9b451819" (MT2002)

Archive: MTOUCHTASK

And if I double click in the error, then I get the message:

File not found: /User/Admin/Desktop/Project/iPhoneProject/MTOUCHTASK

What I'm missing? I have to update somthing else?

P.D.: I Updated Xamarin as well.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/29297453/2096139

Comment: Try to clean the solution and rebuild (I had the same issue. sometimes there are old references in the project build) or try to remove the mvvmcross-references and add it again.

Comment: Thanks@Joehl it was a problem of Profile, I had Profile158 and it shold be Profile78 or Profile259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all a problem with the Profile of the PCL that I used in the xamarin.

I changed all the PCL to use Profile78 and then all worked so far.